# If $a_{n}$ is an increasing sequence that is not bounded above, show that $a_{n}\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My thoughts on this are: assume $a_{n}$ doesn't diverge to infinity, it is increasing so instead must converge to some a but then this a would be an upper bound, yet we said an had no upper bound. This contradiction shows the sequence must diverge to infinity.

Is this enough to show the divergence, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If $a_{n}$ is not bounded above, then for every $M\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ there corresponds a natural number $n_{0}$ s.t $a_{n_{0}}\geq M$. Since $a_{n}$ is increasing, this means that:
\begin{align*}
(\forall M\geq 0)(\exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N})\,\,\text{such that}\,\,(n\geq n_{0} \Rightarrow a_{n}\geq a_{n_{0}} \geq M)
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That strategy works, but you don't need to appeal to proof by contradiction. You showed that if an increasing sequence does not diverge, then it is bounded above. By contrapositive, if an increasing sequence is not bounded above, then it diverges.